# 'I had me a boy': how can we use two subjects?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I listened to  a song which started like "I had me a boy." Why are there two subjects, I and me?  Or why did they use I and me?

Comment: You might want to check out [What does “I got me a woman” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231188/) (closed as "Too Basic" on ELU. Also [Reflexive love: where does “love me some …” come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92883/)

Answer (score 3):

There's only one subject here, *I*, but there are two objects. *Boy* is the direct object, and *me* is an indirect object, designating the recipient or beneficiary of the action just as it does in *He gave me a ring*, *He bought me a ring*. As @Peter suggests, this unusual ditransitive use with *have* suggests something along the lines of "I had a boy of my very own".

Answer (score 0):

Linguists are actually still trying to understand this construction!

[Stacey Conroy](http://ling.umd.edu/~staceyc/CUNY08.pdf) suggests that such "personal datives" are simply reflexive pronouns. However, [Corinne Hutchison and Grant Armstrong](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=1L2LAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA178&dq=personal%20dative%20armstrong&ots=ibG77sbSrY&sig=aciVmHk_w9XfpEjvzIbNGTEb-Sc#v=onepage&q=personal%20dative%20armstrong&f=false) build upon Conroy's works and argue that "personal datives" are reflexive pronouns that mean that the verb *satisfies* the subject in some sense.

In other words, this means something like "I had a boy, and it was satisfying to me".

> I had me a boy.

Answer (score -1):

> I had me

is a shortened intensifier, possibly slang, form of

> I had *something* especially for me

it may also be attributed to southern regional AmE accents

> I had a good dinner
>
> I had me a good dinner
>   *I had a superb dinner which was tasty and filled me up*

Comment: This reflexive goes back centuries, surviving in regional dialects, whereas slang is ephemeral.